# Sending a greeting to a deceased relative

Tags: facebook

How can I send a message to a deceased member on Facebook if I have not asked to be friended?

Answer (score 2):

Facebook lets users block others from writing to them without first becoming Facebook friends, so if you don't see a Message button on the user's profile, you cannot send a greeting to a non-FB friend.